# Is it possible to set an email account to not bother checking in a certain timeframe each day?

Tags: sync, email, battery

According to Battery Saver, email is the single biggest use of battery on my phone, and since Windows Phone 8.1, there is an option to check for messages "based on my usage", and underneath it'll show currently syncing "as items arrive" or "every 2 hours", etc. Is it possible, perhaps through Cortana, to set it up to change these sync settings on a schedule?

For example, so I could have it flip to "manually" between 22:00 and 7:00 daily, or to not check my Exchange account on weekends, or when my calendar says I'm out of the office?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you won't find an app in the store to do that as developers don't have access to the necessary APIs.

I do think enabling quiet hours will disable email push, so you should try that. I'll check if I can verify this.

Comment: Quiet hours do not stop email push.  It only stops the phone from making a noise r vibrating when mail comes in.